# why tkinter error rise when using turtle on pycharm

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm new to Python, so I'm trying some turtle basic codes using PyCharm IDE but this error keep raising

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amerm/Desktop/CP_1/Turtle_new.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

the code is

```
t_1 = turtle.Turtle()

t_1.speed(1)

t_1.forward(100)
t_1.left(45)
t_1.forward(100)

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying

> If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

Since you've evidently (`/usr/local/Cellar` is the smoking gun evidence) installed Python from Homebrew, you'll also have to install the tk package separately:

```
brew install python-tk@3.9
```

and try again.

Comment: Wow, that was fast and helpful, thanks, still need 10 min to accept your answer